# Как увеличить размерность входных данных для torch.nn.Linear?

Tags: pytorch

Допустим есть обученный слой **torch.nn.Linear**. Мне нужно добавить один вход к этому слою и инициализировав его веса случайным образом. А остальные веса нужно чтобы не менялись. Понятно, что нужно сделать переформирование тензора weights, и вопрос, есть ли для этого типовая функция?

Для примера, был слой:

```
self.layer = nn.Linear(10, 15)
```

И переделать его в слой

```
self.layer = nn.Linear(11, 15)
```

Сохранив те веса, которые уже были у nn.Linear(10, 15)